# Fuzzy Template matching?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm attempting to wrap my head around the basics of CV. The bit that initially got me interested was template matching (it was mentioned in a Pycon talk unrelated to CV), so I figured I'd start there.

I started with this image:

[image: Scene from SMB3]

Out of which I want to detect Mario. So I cut him out:

[image: The Plumber]

I understand the concept of sliding the template around the image to see the best fit, and following a tutorial, I'm able to find mario with the following code:

```
def match_template(img, template):
    s = time.time()
    img_size = cv.GetSize(img)
    template_size = cv.GetSize(template)

    img_result = cv.CreateImage((img_size[0] - template_size[0] + 1, 
                            img_size[1] - template_size[1] + 1), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
    cv.Zero(img_result)

    cv.MatchTemplate(img, template, img_result, cv.CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.MinMaxLoc(img_result)
    # inspect.getargspec(cv.MinMaxLoc)
    print min_val
    print max_val 
    print min_loc 
    print max_loc
    cv.Rectangle(img, max_loc, (max_loc[0] + template.width, max_loc[1] + template.height), cv.Scalar(120.), 2)
    print time.time() - s
    cv.NamedWindow("Result")
    cv.ShowImage("Result", img)
    cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

So far so good, but then I came to realize that this is incredibly fragile. It will only ever find Mario with that specific background, and with that specific animation frame being displayed.

So I'm curious, given that Mario will always have the same Mario-ish attributes, (size, colors) is there a technique with which I could find him regardless of whether his currect frame is standing still, or one of the various run cycle sprites? Kind of like fuzzy matching that you can do on strings, but for images.

Maybe since he's the only red thing, there is a way of simply tracking the red pixels?

The whole other issue is removing the background from the template. Maybe that would help the MatchTemplate function find Mario even though he doesn't exactly match the tempate? As of now, I'm not entirely sure how that would work ( I see that there is a mask param in MatchTemplate, but I'll have to investigate further)

My main question is whether or not template matching is the way to go about detecting an image that is mostly the same, but varies (like when he's walking), or is there another technique I should look into?

### Update:

### Attempts at matching other Marios

---

Going off of mmgp's suggestion that it should be workable for matching other things, I ran a couple of tests.

I used this as the template to match:

[image: Super mario]

And then took a couple of screen shots to test the matching against.

For the first, I successfully find Mario, and get a max value of 1.

[image]

However, trying to find jumping Mario results in a complete misfire.

[image: Misfire]

Now granted, the mario in the template, and the mario in the scene is facing opposite directions, as well as being different animation frames, but I would think they still match a *lot* more than anything else in the image -- if only for the colors alone. But it targets the platform as being the closest match to the template.

Note that the max value for this one was `0.728053808212`.

Next I tried a scene *without* mario to see what would happen.

[image]

But oddly enough, I get the *exact* result as the image with jumping mario -- right down to the similarity value: `0.728053808212`. Mario being in the picture is just as accurate as him *not* being in the picture.

Really strange! I don't know the actual details of the underlying algorithm, but I'd imagine, from a standard deviation perspective, the boxes in the scene that at least match the Red in template Mario's suit would be closer to the mean distance than a blue platform, right? So, it's extra confusing that it's not even in the general area of where I would expect it to be.

I'm guessing this is user error on my end, or maybe just a misunderstanding.

Why would a scene with a similar Mario have as much of a match as a scene with no Mario at all?

Comment: Given the nature of the application you are working with, template matching can work pretty well and should be considered until you can show a good example of where it fails. Your application doesn't require neither scale invariance or translation invariance, and only a bit of rotation invariance -- the only problem I can see is when Mario is ducking. To solve that, just consider a different template where Mario is ducking and then you do the template matching twice. Doing the matching by red colors is certainly possible, but you will need to combine it with another tool to make it adequate.

Comment: @mmgp I added a few examples of the failures I'm getting. I'm having pretty poor luck matching anything other than something which has an exact copy of my template. I added a couple pictures so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Fair enough. Here is a result I can get: http://i.imgur.com/6RfS51J.png (yellow rectangle), for the image without Mario the maximum cross-correlated point I got was ~0.34. Clarification: I used only the red channel, from which I calculated interior morphological gradient from both input and template, and only then I performed the cross-correlation. The maximum value I got was ~0.44, which is low but justifiable. The template is very different from the Mario in that other frame, for instance now I see two hands, two eyes, two feet, and  about everything else is at least slightly different too.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more: the cross-correlation doesn't care about any spatial similarity (or shape, etc) at all, it is just comparing individual pixels across the channels in the template and input image. So, a "bad matched" pixel can be compensated by a fully matched one, thus possibly making the cross-correlation return high values for unwanted areas. Your Mario template has a couple of cyan background pixels which might better match the blue tone in the platform when doing individual comparisons using RGB, explaining the bad match you get. Including a sample video might be a good idea.

Comment: Template matching is a very fragile technique only useable if the objects look nearly the same in each frame.
If the object keeps the same size and similar shape, you might want to try chamfer matching with the contour (and maybe the inner edges) of the object as a mask.
If the object keeps similar colors which differ from the background, you might want to extract a color histogram from the object and detect regions in the image with similar histograms.
If you want to solve that concrete Mario problem it might be better to "track" Mario instead of detecting him or extract+delete the background

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No method is infallible, but template matching do have a good chance to work there. It might require some pre-processing, and until there is a larger sample (a short video for example) to demonstrate the possible problems, there isn't much point in trying more advanced methods simply because some library implement them for you -- especially if you don't know under which conditions they are expected to work.

For instance, here are the results I get using template matching (red rectangles) -- all them are using the template https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYs9B.png, even the last one:

[image]  [image] [image] [image]

To achieve that I started by considering only the red channel of both the template and the input image. From that we easily calculate the internal morphological gradient and only then perform the matching. In order to not get a rectangle when Mario is not present, it is needed to set a minimum threshold for the matching. Here is the template and one of the images after these two transformations:

[image] [image]

And here is some sample code to achieve that:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])

img2 = img[:,:,2]
img2 = img2 - cv2.erode(img2, None)
template = cv2.imread(sys.argv[2])[:,:,2]
template = template - cv2.erode(template, None)

ccnorm = cv2.matchTemplate(img2, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
print ccnorm.max()
loc = numpy.where(ccnorm == ccnorm.max())
threshold = 0.4
th, tw = template.shape[:2]
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    if ccnorm[pt[::-1]] < threshold:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + tw, pt[1] + th),
            (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite(sys.argv[2], img)
```

I expect it to fail in more varied situations, but there are a couple of easy adjustments to be done.

Answer (score 12):

Template matching doesn't always give good results. you should look into Keypoints matching.

### Step1: Find Keypoints

Let's assume that you managed to cut out Mario or get ROI image of mario. Make this image your template image. Now, find keypoints in the main image and also in the template. So now you have two sets of keypoints. One for the image and other for Mario(template).

You can use [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform), [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF), [ORB](http://amarsinghhpcs.blogspot.com/2013/06/surf-freak-brisk-orb-classes-in-opencv.html) depending on your preferences.

[EDIT]:

This is what I got using this method with SIFT and flann based knn matching. I haven't done the bounding box part.

[image]

Since your template is very small, SIFT and SURF would not give many keypoints. But to get good number of feature points, you could try Harris Corner detector. I applied Harris corner on the image and I got pretty good points on Mario.

[image]

### Step2: Match Keypoints

If you have used SIFT or SURF, you'd have descriptors of both the image and the template. Match these keypoints using KNN or some other efficient matching algorithm. If you are using OpenCV, I'd suggest you to look into flannbased matcher. After matching the keypoints, you would want to filter out the incorrect matches. You can do this by K- nearest neighbors and depending upon the distance of the nearest match you can further filter out keypoints. You can further filter your matches using Forward-Backward Error.

#### Forward-Backward Error Estimation:

1. Match template keypoints to the image keypoints This will give you a set of matches.
2. Match the image keypoints to the template keypoints. This will give you another set of matches.
3. Common set of both these set will filter out incorrect matches.

[image]

[EDIT]:
If you are using Harris Corner detector, you'd get only points and not keypoints. You can either convert them into keypoints or write your own brute force mathcer. It's not that difficult.

### Step3: Estimation

After filtering the keypoints, you'd have a cluster of keypoints near your object (in this case, Mario) and few scattered keypoints. To eliminate these scattered keypoints, you could use clustering. DBSCAN clustering will help you get a good cluster of points.

### step4: Bounding Box Estimation

Now you have a cluster of keypoints. Using k-means, you should try to find the center of the cluster. Once you obtain the center of the cluster, you can estimate the bounding box.

I hope this helps.

[EDIT]

Trying to match points using **Harris Corners**. After filtering Harris corners, I'm using brute force method to match the points. some better algorithm might give you better results.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe you have tried any of this in regard of the question's application, instead this sound as a generic answer as much as it can get. I quickly tried SURF, although I had no hope for good results since it is really not intended to give good results in the situations shown. As a starter the template is too small to give decent key points by multi-scale gaussian filtering and gaussians difference, in fact it gives me one single key point in the middle of Mario's hand. I padded the template in order to SURF obtain more keypoints, but it finds no corresponding matches between images.

Comment: I have tried this and it works well. Yeah, I get the problem here. your template is too small. Generally this works really well on template of size greater than 150x150

Comment: I'm saying you didn't try this approach on this problem, did you ? If so, post your results please.

Comment: I tried SIFT. I got 3 points on Mario. but matching is horrible.

Comment: Now you say matching with Harris shouldn't be difficult, but can you show that it works ? In special, can you match Mario in that other frame using Harris ? I don't believe this work either. You are attempting to use methods that are not meant for the situations shown: what you are trying to match is not a rotation, scale, or translation transformation from the original image (template). And I'm not seeing how you are going to match using purely the corner responses from Harris, I expect a lot of false matches.

Comment: I'm getting better matches if I double the size of the mario template

Comment: A very nice answer as it currently stands although I agree that it might not be adequate or the simplest approach for this problem.